# In C for postfix and prefix operator, operand should be an lvalue, so what actually lvalue means for a pointer variable in case of these operators?

Tags: c, postfix-mta, lvalue

In C for postfix and prefix operator, operand should be an l value, so if cp = &ch; and assume that address of ch is 1000 and address of cp is 5000 so ++cp should be 5001 or 1001 ?

This doubt arises because lvalue of cp is location of cp(5000) and rvalue of cp is value at 5000, "that is 1000". So if ++ operator works on lvalue then it should increment 5000 and not the 1000(because it's an rvalue)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An lvalue is something (an address) that can receive a value (assignment). Incrementing an lvalue usually increments the address where to assign the rvalue to.

Comment: You might be able to get more useful answers showing a little snippet of code. I find it a little difficult to determine what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have for example these two declarations

```
char ch = 'A';
char *cp = &ch;
```

Then this expression `++cp` increases the value stored in the variable `cp`. The value is the address of the variable `ch` So after the increment the value stored in the variable cp will point to the memory that is after the memory occupied by the variable ch.

The unary operator ++ can change a value of an lvalue expression.  You may not for example to write

```
char ch = 'A';
`++&ch;`
```

because the expression `&ch` yields a value of the address.

It is the same as to write

```
++3;
```

instead of

```
int x = 3;
++x;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the C11 standard(ISO-IEC-9899-2011)--6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays and function designators: [HTML_version](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html) [pdf_version](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> Except when it is **the operand of** the sizeof operator, the unary & operator, the ++
> operator, the -- operator, or **the left operand of** the . operator or an assignment operator,
> an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated
> object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called lvalue conversion.

Actually, [the result of & operator is rvalue](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p3) and [the result of * operator is lvalue](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p4), so:

```c
int *p1; //variable p1 is a lvalue
int num = 314; //variable num is a lvalue
p1 = &num; //num is still a lvalue, and keep it that way
int *p2 = p1 + 1; //p1 is still a lvalue, but will become a rvalue through lvalue conversion
```